# R: Extracting latitude, longitude and time from JSON file

Tags: r, json

I have a `.json` file (more than 100,000 lines) containing the following information:

```
POST /log?lat=36.804121354&lon=-1.270256482&time=2016-05-18T17:39:59.004Z
{ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'content-length': '29',
  host: 'ip_address:port',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.7.0' }
BODY: lat=36.804121354&lon=-1.270256482

POST /log?lat=36.804123256&lon=-1.270254711&time=2016-05-18T17:40:13.004Z
{ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'content-length': '29',
  host: 'ip_address:port',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.7.0' }
BODY: lat=36.804123256&lon=-1.270254711

POST /log?lat=36.804124589&lon=-1.270255641&time=2016-05-18T17:41:05.004Z
{ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'content-length': '29',
  host: 'ip_address:port',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.7.0' }
BODY: lat=36.804124589&lon=-1.270255641

.......
```

The above information repeats with updated `latitude`, `longitude` and `time`. Using `R`, how can I extract latitude, longitude and time from this file? and store them in a `dataframe` like this:

```
id  lat           lon            time
1   36.804121354  -1.270256482   2016-05-18 17:39:59
2   36.804123256  -1.270254711   2016-05-18 17:40:13
3   36.804124589  -1.270255641   2016-05-18 17:41:05
```

Comment: What have you tried? `jsonlite::fromJSON` is a good place to start. But it's hard to know how to help when we don't know what you tried and where you're stuck...

Comment: You should post the beginning of the file with more than one instance of the text records.

Comment: @42- Just updated the question as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear your data is strictly JSON.  Since the requested data is all contained on the "Post" lines, an one solution is to filter those lines out and then parse them.

```
#Read lines
x<-readLines("test.txt")
#Find lines beginning with "POST"
posts<-x[grep("^POST", x)]
#Remove the prefix: "POST /log?"
posts<-sub("^POST /log\\?", "", posts)
#split remaining fields on the &
fields<-unlist(strsplit(posts, "\\&"))

#remove the prefixes ("lat=", "lon=", "time=")
fields<-sub("^.*=", "", fields)

#make a dataframe (assume the fields are always in the same order)
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(fields, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df)<-c("lat", "lon", "time") 
#convert the columns to the proper type.
df$lat<-as.numeric(df$lat)
df$lon<-as.numeric(df$lon)
df$time<-as.POSIXct(df$time, "%FT%T", tz="UTC")
```